# How to get results from an EXACT date in MySQL? (Not an interval)

Tags: sql, database, date, mariadb, exact-match

So in my query, I simply need to narrow down the results by whoever's status was last updated 3 weeks ago.

The line:

`AND DATE_ADD(user_status_updated, INTERVAL - 21 DAY)`

returns the results as an interval from now and 21 days from now. I am only interested in the exact date 21 days ago, but cannot find the right function to use.

I am writing automatic emails and part of this project is to check daily for users that have been inactive for 3 weeks, so it will always be a matter of NOW() minus 21 days. But I don't want the interval, I want the exact 21 days ago since last updated results.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my solution.

```
WHERE user_status_updated= DATE_SUB(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL 21 DAY)
```

The user_status_updated is a DATETIME field

Comment: That won't work unless you are storing just a date in that column.  In that case, the column may as well be `DATE` instead of `DATETIME`.